# When can I do the supply missions?

Tags: zombies-run

I super love "playing" [Zombies, Run!](https://www.zombiesrungame.com/) - the story missions are fun and are getting me outside and exercising, which is super cool.

Ideally, I would like to alternate my story runs with supply runs to make the story missions last longer, as it were, but when I looked at the mission list earlier today in order to figure out what mission I wanted to run tomorrow, I noticed the supply missions are still locked.

When do they unlock? Is it at some point during the story? Or do I have to do something like complete the whole story?

Comment: If you run the 30 minute stories, you could run the 60 minute story in the settings instead and simply resume on your second workout. This would effectively double your "storytime".

Answer (score 1):

Chronologically, the Supply Run missions are supposed to take place [throughout Season One](https://o0yono0o.tumblr.com/post/160331071010/zombies-run-chronological-mission-order). You should be able to run them at any time.
As this question is a bit dated, it's possible the Supply Runs were still in development or required a purchase when you asked the question, but they should now be unlocked and available [for no additional charge](http://blog.zombiesrungame.com/post/60348260308/supply-missions-have-returned-to-zombies-run). You should not have to complete the whole story before receiving access to the Supply Runs, but if they somehow still show up locked, you may have to update your app, run the first mission, or upgrade your base before you get access.